# Cardinality Proof Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Suppose A and B are sets such that card A ≤ card B. Prove that there exists a set C ⊆ B such that card C = card A.

I know that there is only an injection from A to B. I'm having trouble showing that set C which is a subset of B has the same cardinality as set A.

Comment: Hint: Consider the image of your injection.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\text{card}(A)\leq \text{card}(B)$, there is an injection $f\colon A\to B$. Then $f\colon A\to f(A)$ is a bijection, and $f(A)\subseteq B$.

Comment: I understand that $f(A) \subseteq B$, my issue is that there is another set $C \subseteq B$ and showing that cardC = cardA.

Comment: Take $C=f(A)$. This is the set you are looking for.

Comment: @Heinrich What are you not seeing? $f\colon A\to f(A)$ is a bijection. Yes there might be several other $C$ (e.g. if $f$ is not also a surjection, or if $B$ is infinite), but you don't care: you only need one, and $C= f(A)$ works.

Comment: I see where I went wrong, I assumed off the bat there is no possibility of a surjection f: $A \rightarrow B$. So afterwards you assume C = f(A)?

Comment: @Heinrich If $f\colon A\to B$ is an injection then $f$ is a bijection $A\to f(A) = C \subseteq B$.

Comment: @Heinrich I'm not entirely sure what you are having trouble with. You want to find a $C\subseteq B$, such that there is a bijection $f\colon A\to C$ (because this would mean that $A$ and $C$ have the same cardinality). I have found a subset of $B$, namely $f(A)$ for which there is such a bijection. In conclusion, if I let $C=f(A)$, then I have shown that $A$ and $C$ have the same cardinality.